# how to change cifs timeout

Tags: linux, samba, cifs

Happens when from my laptop I change wifi network that I've to wait 5 minutes before that I can umount cifs share.

```
mount -t cifs //ip/share /home/user/net/share -o user=user,pass=pass
```

I didn't found any information on internet, only tune cifsFYI:

```
echo > 1 /proc/fs/cifs/cifsFYI
```

but nothing changes...

Is there a way to change cifs timeout?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
umount -l /home/user/net/share
```

From the man page for umount: -l:  lazy  unmount. Detach the filesystem from the filesystem hierarchy now, and cleanup all references to the filesystem as soon as it is not busy anymore.

You can also try umount -f (forcibly unmount) but it may not work on cifs filesystems.